# Why can't you specify template argument for constructor template

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-argument-deduction

A while back I wanted to write a class that could return a pointer to a type, that was initialised with the same parameters all the time. As this only returns pointers, if I wanted to create an object returning `A*`, but generating `B*`, which is a child of `A`, there would not be an issue, as `B*` is castable to `A*`. I wanted to store these in a vector, but I didn't really care whether the generated type was `B` or `C`, only that it was a child of `A`. I wanted to do something like:

```cpp
template<class RET_TYPE>
class Generator {
    public:
        template <class GEN_TYPE, class... Args> requires requires (Args...){
            { new GEN_TYPE(Args...) } -> std::convertible_to<RET_TYPE*>;
        }
        Generator (Args...) { /* Implementation */ }
        RET_TYPE getObject() { /* Implementation */}
};
```

The only issue is that as far as I found there is no way to specify the template parameters of the constructor. In the end I used a workaround, but I did not find a good explanation as to why this was the case. The most in detail I found one , talked about the constructor not actually possessing a name as such, but surely if that was the only issue it can be solved by: `Generator<class template><Constructor template>()`, no? The issue I see with this is name resolution, but it shouldn't be a problem, as it is unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the explanation from the standard, [[temp.arg.explicit]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.arg.explicit#8):

> [Note 4: Because the explicit template argument list follows the function template name, and because constructor templates ([class.ctor]) are named without using a function name ([class.qual]), there is no way to provide an explicit template argument list for these function templates. — end note]

And [[class.ctor.general]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.ctor.general#1):

> Constructors do not have names.

Comment: I get this, but people wrote this standard, so is there a reason why a way to pass templates to the constructor omitted (like a technical issue it would cause)?

Comment: @Lala5th I think the committee just doesn't want to make such special syntax for constructor template, and template argument deduction would work fine for most cases.

Comment: I didn't consider that but it seems fair